# Polymorphism design fault

Tags: java, polymorphism

**Background:**

I have 4 classes that represent a unit of measure: Mm, Inch, Pixel, FootAndInch.

Each class is a wrapper class for BigDecimal, they each have the same subset of methods:

```
...
add(BigDecimal value)
divide(BigDecimal value)
multiple(BigDecimal value)
subtract(BigDecimal value)
...
```

It seemed tedious to repeat the same methods in each individual class. So I created an abstract class (called "Unit") hoping I would only have to write each method once and make use of polymorphism:

```
public abstract class Unit {

BigDecimal value;

public Unit(BigDecimal value) {
    this.value = value;
}
public Unit(int value) {
    this.value = new BigDecimal(value);
}
public Unit(String value) {
    this.value = new BigDecimal(value);
}
public Unit(Unit unit) {
    this.value = unit.bigDecimal();
}

public abstract Unit add(int value);
public abstract Unit add(int value, MathContext mathContext);
public abstract Unit add(Unit value);
public abstract Unit add(Unit value, MathContext mathContext);   
public abstract Unit add(BigDecimal value);
public abstract Unit add(BigDecimal value, MathContext mathContext);

public abstract Unit divide(Unit value, MathContext mathContext);
public abstract Unit divide(int value, MathContext mathContext);
public abstract Unit divide(BigDecimal value, MathContext mathContext);

public abstract Unit[] divideAndRemainder(Unit value, MathContext mathContext);

public abstract Unit multiply(BigDecimal value);   
public abstract Unit multiply(BigDecimal value, MathContext mathContext);
public abstract Unit multiply(int value);
public abstract Unit multiply(int value, MathContext mathContext);
public abstract Unit multiply(Unit value);
public abstract Unit multiply(Unit value, MathContext mathContext);    

public abstract Unit negate();
public abstract Unit plus();
public abstract Unit remainder(Unit value, MathContext mathContext);

public abstract Unit subtract(int value);
public abstract Unit subtract(int value, MathContext mathContext);
public abstract Unit subtract(Unit value);
public abstract Unit subtract(Unit value, MathContext mathContext);   
public abstract Unit subtract(BigDecimal value);
public abstract Unit subtract(BigDecimal value, MathContext mathContext); 

public double doubleValue() {
    return value.doubleValue();
}    
public float floatValue() {
    return value.floatValue();
}    
public int intValue() {
    return value.intValue();
}
public BigDecimal bigDecimal() {
    return value;
}

@Override public abstract String toString();    
}
```

And now Mm, Inch, Pixel, FootAndInch each extend Unit

**The Problem:**
The following statement kicks up an error:

```
Mm value1 = new Mm(1000);
Mm result = value1.divide(new Mm(10), new MathContext(10, RoundingMode.CEILING));
```

"incompatible types: Unit cannot be converted to Mm".

I understand the error, but I don't know how to rearrange my code so that I'm only writing the methods once. Any advice?

**Edit:**
Just to clarify, the Unit class methods are implemented in the Unit class. I didn't include them to try and shorten the question.

Comment: have you considered parameterizing your classes?

Comment: Is this the same as Generics?

Comment: yes, apparently I forgot the proper term

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see 2 options: either make only 1 class that keeps an int and an enum for the measurement type (no polymorphism required). Or turn Unit into a generic superclass Unit and make all of your abstract function return the type T. Then define Mm to be class Mm extends Unit.

Comment: Each subclass has a method of converting it's value to another, so for example: Class Mm has the methods toInch(), toPixel(), toFootAndInch(). This is outside the scope of an enum, correct?

I'll look into Generics, thanks.

Comment: Also see how TimeUnit works, it's a good example for the first option.

Comment: Quick look into this and it seems Generics is the way to go. I assumed this is what polymorphism was used for.